# Computer invaded by popup-like box from themoscowtimes.com

Tags: google-chrome

At least, I think it's some kind of popup. Here's a screen shot, it's the box with the "MT" on the left. [image]

The box is not really a popup, or at least doesn't behave like one--I can't close it and it stays always on top of any window. The story it displays does change. I'm running Chrome. I don't see anything that shouldn't be there in the extensions. I'm running Debian Jessie with Gnome 3.14.1. I don't see anything obviously fishy in running processes, though I'm no expert. I have restarted and it's still there. I believe it does not appear until I open chrome.

EDIT: In some respects the box behaves as if it's not there: if I click on certain parts of it, the click will act on whatever the box is covering.  But if I click right on the text it opens a tab in chrome displaying the article that the box is previewing.

Comment: If I were to hazard to guess that is being added by one of your extensions.  Although what is strange, is the notification, doesn't appear to have been even generated by Chrome

Comment: @SpiderPig yeah, this is clearly a notification. This happens if a webpage shows a popup saying: "This website wants to show notifications. Do you want to allow it?" and you click yes. In my opinion, your comment should be posted as an answer.

Comment: Yes that was it. I could not find a bell icon, but I typed notifications into the settings dialog box and indeed, there was themoscowtimes.com under "Allowed". Thanks, please make it an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: The true extent of the Russian hacking scandal grows by the day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That box is a notification.
Open a new tab in Chrome and click on the bell icon in the upper right corner. Then click the cog wheel and disable notifications from the moscow times.

Or, if you don't have/can't find the bell icon, go to Settings->Advanced-> Content->Notifications, and remove the offending web site from the list titled "Allow".

Comment: "cock wheel"? ;)

Comment: Freud wuz here.